# increasing process

Tags: probability

Let $A_t=|B_t|-\int_0^tsgn(B_s)dB_s$ with $sgn(B_s)=-1$ if $x>0$ and $sgn(x)=1$ if $x \leq 0$
Show $\{A_t,t \geq 0 \}$ is an increasing process and $\{|B_t|:t \geq 0 \}$ is a semimartingale.

For $A_t$, I try to show $A_t \geq A_{t+1}$ but I don't suceed.
For $|B_t|$,$|B_t|=\int_0^tsgn(B_s)dB_s+A_t$ and $\int_0^t B_sdB_s$ is a martingale, but $A_t$ is not a bounded process

Thank you

Comment: well, this follows from the Tanaka's formula (trivially), but I am guessing that is not the answer you are looking for. So maybe you want to look into a proof for Tanaka's formula.

Comment: ok I will see a proof